# Incorrect answer show for multiplication by using loops in java

Tags: java

I try to compute 5*10*15*...50 by using for ,while and do-while loop respectively. When i run my code,it shows the incorrect answer which equal to 0. I cant find out the problem in my code. Can someone please help me to look at it?? Appreciate it very much~~ Below is my codes:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ForMethod show1 = new ForMethod();  
        show1.computeForLoop();
        System.out.println();

        DWMethod show2 = new DWMethod();
        show2.computeDWLoop();
        System.out.println();

        WhileMethod show3 = new WhileMethod();
        show3.computeWhileLoop();

    }

}


// For Loop
public class ForMethod {

    long mul;

    public void computeForLoop(){

        System.out.println("Compute using For Loop : ");
        for(int x = 1; x <= 10 ; x++){

            if ( x < 10){

                System.out.print(x*5 + " x ");

            } else { System.out.print(x*5);}

            mul *= x*5;
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe Product of Number = " + mul);

    }
}


// While Loop Method
public class WhileMethod {

    int x = 1 ;
    long mul;

    public void computeWhileLoop(){

                System.out.println("Compute using While Loop : ");

        while(x < 10){

            System.out.print(x*5 + " x ");
            x++;


            if (x == 10){

                System.out.print(x*5);
            }

            mul *= (x*5);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Product of Number = " + mul);
    }


}


// Do-While Loop Method
public class DWMethod {

    int x = 1;
    long mul;

    public void computeDWLoop(){

            System.out.println("Compute using Do-While Loop : ");

        do{

            if (x < 10 ){

                System.out.print(x*5 + " x ");

            } else

                if (x == 10){

                    System.out.print(x*5);
                }

            mul *= x;
            x++;

        } while (x <= 10);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Product of Number = " + mul);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is probably that the product of all these numbers is too large and overflows your `long` variable.

Comment: Initialize `mul` to 1 as by default it will be 0.

Comment: You need to use `BigInteger` rather than `long`.

Comment: thanks for all the help..after i change my code, it show the correct answer for for loop and do-while loop which equal to 3.54375 x 10^13..but the answer for while loop show different answer with others which is 7.0875 x 10^12...how can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `mul` field is initialised to zero. This means you are always multiplying by zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `mul`. If you do not initialize `mul`, the computer gives it the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

you should give to initialize `mul` with value 1

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to initialise mul to "5" then start looping on 2 !